How to emulate Python nested or "sub" attributes
How can I track a sub-attribute that applies to some attributes but not others? It seems such a thing does not exist, but please confirm.
I read some similar questions here and here, but one answer is quite old and the other is closed.
Consider the example:
class FoodTest:
    def __init__(self, food_group, food, variety=''):
        self.food_group = food_group
        self.food = food
        self.variety = variety

    def get_food(self):
        print(f'I like {self.food}s, which are a {self.food_group}')
        
        if self.food == 'apple':
            print(f'The {self.food} variety is {self.variety}')
        
        
oran = FoodTest('fruit', 'orange')
oran.get_food()

app = FoodTest('fruit', 'apple', 'fuji')
app.get_food()

Output:
I like oranges, which are a fruit
I like apples, which are a fruit
The apple variety is fuji

What I want is a variety only for apples (fuji, granny smith, etc.) but not for oranges. Of course I can access app.variety, but what I'm really looking for is "app.food.variety".

Do you want to create an Apple class that derives from the FoodTest class? https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance

@001 I don't know. Yes, if it serves the purpose. I just have to keep track of many attributes and look them up later.

To have sub-attributes, you could use sub-classes.  Each Food knows its attributes.
class Food:
    def __init__(self, food_group, food):
        self.food_group = food_group
        self.food = food

    def get_food(self):
        print(f'I like {self.food}s, which are a {self.food_group}')

class Apple(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('fruit', 'apple')
        self.variety = 'fuji'  # extra attribute for apple

    def get_food(self):
        super().get_food()
        # Extra sentence for variety
        print(f'The {self.food} variety is {self.variety}')

class Orange(Food):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('fruit', 'orange')

oran = Orange()
oran.get_food()

app = Apple()
app.get_food()

Output:
I like oranges, which are a fruit
I like apples, which are a fruit
The apple variety is fuji

